# j2me incorrect time when resume midlet in windows mobile 6.1

Tags: windows, date, mobile, java-me

I have a strange problem, in my midlet (CLDC 1.1, MIDP 2.0) when windows mobile enters in standby mode (screen turns off) and then when it resume (press any key), I need current time, and I've got an incorrect time! it is like clock stop when midlet is in pause...
This occurrs in windows mobile 6.1 with javafx. In Symbian it doesn't happend, neighter windows mobile 6.5 (with JBlend kvm). I've installed JBLend in windwos mobile 6.1 but no succed

Any idea guys?

Thanks for any advice